# Using generics to return a RavenDB StreamResult

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, ravendb, querydsl

I am struggling to keep my code compact and most importantly, staying true to the "don't repeat yourself" principle when dealing with RavenDB's querydsl types (i.e. types I have stored in the db).
I have two cases which force me to copy/paste methods or litter the code with if statements:

- I would like to pass a *generic* querydsl type to the method as an argument
- I would like to return a generic querydsl type from a method

First case: something like this

```
public int RetrieveStuff(<myGenericType>)
{
    QGenericType qgt= QGenericType.GenericType;
    IRavenQueryable<GenericType> query = session.query(GenericType.class, "GenericType/ByName");
}
```

Second case:

```
public CloseableIterator<StreamResult<GenericType>> RetrieveMoreStuff(String id)
{
    doSomething();
    return Session.advanced().stream(query); //type depends on the operation
}
```

Since I can't compile the methods as indicated above, I am forced to create a separate (yet functionally identical) method for each type ! Like this:

```
private CloseableIterator<StreamResult<supertype>> retrieveStuff();
private CloseableIterator<StreamResult<subtype1>> retrieveStuff1();
private CloseableIterator<StreamResult<subtype2>> retrieveStuff2();
```

etc.

I'm unclear on the following:

- Is this a Java generics-related issue, or do the Querydsl types strongly "bind" to the types they are given when created ? In other words, is the type onto which the Querydsl type "maps" inseparably linked from the Querydsl type ?
- Why can't I do this: 
  `IRavenQueryable<supertype> query = session.query(subtype.class, "Something/ByName")` ?
- Is it possible *at all* to apply polymorphism in this way with querydsl types and the types stored in RavenDB ? If I store a supertype and its subtype(s) in RavenDB, can I somehow make the interaction with the collections generic in the querying code ?

If it is possible *in principle*, I would very much appreciate a valid method signature and minimal code inside to get the query working.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow, but how about: IRavenQueryable<? extends Animal> query = session.query(Dog.class) ?
In general QueryDSL is only used for 'type safe' properties access. If my hint doesn't solve your problem, then please post link to gist explaining your case.

Comment: Marcin, that's pretty much it - I think. I'll try this right away and get back to you. The types that I'm storing in Raven are "complex" types, but their data members are all primitives: String, int and double. Does that mean that it would qualify as "type safe properties access" ? I'm guessing it would. Thanks for taking the time to answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
IRavenQueryable<? extends Animal> query = session.query(Dog.class)
```

However to model polymorphic query you should use `WhereEntityIs` in your index:
Example: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-jvm-client/blob/7845a881d917e1be56aa6913aa5aba85cedd7190/Raven.Client.Java/src/test/java/net/ravendb/client/connection/WhereEntityIsTest.java#L16

The only purpose of QueryDSL is to avoid strings in queries (type safe). It can be used for addressing simple properties, as well as nested. Example:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-jvm-client/blob/68ca05f0f3e158ec1702d64eca11d1e6b5dc8a17/Raven.Client.Java/src/test/java/net/ravendb/tests/querying/UsingDynamicQueryWithRemoteServerTest.java#L127